# Globally-distributed load testing service providers

Tags: load-testing

We are looking for a third-party service providers to load-test our website infrastructure, preferably across multiple geos.

Any recommendations?

We have done internal load testing with Load Runner and JMeter, but we want to see the impact of global latency and higher loads than we can generate in-house.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a load testing tool built on Amazon EC2 that can generate up to 50,000 concurrent vusers from Singapore, California, Virginia, and Ireland.  Would that be enough geo diversity?

We are the lowest cost tool that is cloud-based.  5,000 concurrent vusers costs $199 for one test or $999 for a month of unlimited test runs.  If you want someone to actually create and run the tests, we have partners to help.

Contact me at http://loadstorm.com via the Contact Us form or give me a call at 970-389-1899 if you are interested.

Good luck with your testing and finding a fit with a vendor.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any load generators in Japan?

Answer (score 0):

If you need high global distribution, you should look at the likes of [Gomez](http://www.gomez.com/), Keynote, Webmetrcis.

If the Amazon EC2 distribution is good enough for you, you can use any of the standard load-testing tools (LoadRunner, WebLOAD, etc.) and deploy your load-generators there,.